# Getting an executable jar file to run after creation from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable

I have a few jar files included in my application that i have added to librarys
In net beans these can be read and used

I have tried to create an executable file in netbeans by Clean and build and i have all the necessary properties in build packaging set, however when i try to double click the jar created nothing happens. It is supposed to run the jar from my Main class

Now i tried to go to cmd terminal and do it from there using:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I have added 3 different jars including sqlite-jdbc3.8.7, AbsoluteLayout, miglayout

but what was returned was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load SQLite JDBC driver
        at myapp.database.DatabaseConProvider.<init>(DatabaseConPr
ovider.java:18)
        at myapp.presenter.AppPresenter.<init>(AppPresenter.java
:32)
        at myapp.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at myapp.database.DatabaseConProvider.<init>(DatabaseConPr
ovider.java:16)
        ... 2 more
```

The problem seems to be that its not being able to access the jar files that have been added to the project, because once I execute clean and build the /dist folder in the project only has myapp.jar but should also have README.txt and a lib folder which contains all the librarys. As seen in:

http://netbeanside61.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/making-executable-desktop-application.html

I am using windows 8 with netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: Did you enable "copy dependent libraries" in the Packaging section of the project properties?

Comment: yes i have and it still gives me this error im not sure why it doesnt load my jars if i have done it properly

Comment: @fooll : Have you seen my answer ?

Comment: when you run `ant clean jar` from the CLI, show the `tree` for the `dist` folder.  In that folder, are all your runtime dependencies there?  Specifically, the three JAR's which your project depends upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a explorer you can go to the structure of a .jar file . (Or rename extension .jar to .zip)

- possibility 1
  look at the `MANIFEST.MF` is the there something like

---

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_51-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: Find
```

here the `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar` is in the `lib/` folder outside GUIFormExamples.jar

[image]

- possibility 2
  content of sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar is added to appxx.jar

---

[image]

---

- Case 1
  put the lib folder in the same folder where your appxx.jar is
- Case 2
  must work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

How do you manage your application dependencies? I encourage you not to simply "add jars to your netbeans" - user some kind of project/dependency management tool instead - [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/).

Then, in case of maven, check this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/3080422

Porting your application to maven/gradle project won't take much time (but unfortunately, learning a tool definitely will...) and you gain a lot of flexibility.

Comment: "Netbeans uses Maven, and maven has lib-dependency plugin that generates such entry automatically, scanning all dependencies in your POM file" my friend has tried the same approach on her computer and it works for her on the same project and creates it by clicking the file however when i do it on my computer it doesn't work

Comment: @fooll git to the rescue!  More specifically, github.com is free, there are others, as well.  Not to drown you with irrelevancies, but there's probably a setting in NB which is, or isn't, in the project, which is why the discrepancy. FWIW, the pain and hassle of, specifically, gradle is, IMHO, worth it.  NB supports gradle with a plugin.